# invisible div on scroll

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a navigation bar which fades in when the user scrolls down. Right now I'm simply trying to get it to do anything when the user scrolls down, because I've tried to do a number of scripts, and it isn't working.

I'm referencing the script like this in my HTML document:

```
<body onload-src="nav.js">
```

And this is my script:

```
  function nav() {  
    if (window.pageYOffset > 500) {
      document.getElementById("scrollnav").style.visibility="invisible";
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById("scrollnav").style.visibility="visible";
    }
  }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! I know lots of people have asked questions like this, but I would really like to understand what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`invisible` is not a valid value for `visibility`.

What you probably want is `hidden`:

```
document.getElementById("scrollnav").style.visibility="hidden";
```

[Here is a reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility).

You should also make sure the element actually exists before accessing the `style` property. It may not seem important, but if you intend on using the code for the foreseeable future then you will most likely run into errors at some point.

```
function nav() {  
    var elem = document.getElementById("scrollnav");
    if ( ! elem) {
        console.warn("#scrollnav was not found on the page");
        return;
    }
    if (window.pageYOffset > 500) {
        elem.style.visibility="invisible";
    } else {
        elem.style.visibility="visible";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It still doesn't seem to be working tho :P I'm hosting on Neocities, which accepts Java and all that, but I don't know what else to try.